# Why ng-repeat is not working correctly?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am looping an array with `ng-repeat` but it only displays what is write in `{{ }}`.

There is not any error in the console though it's not displaying properly...
Here is the code

```
    <html ng-app="mittens">
    <head>
        <title>Mittens</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" href="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" href="mittens.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body ng-controller="mittensController">
        <div class="container">

            <h3 ng-repeat="meow in meows">{{meow}}</h3>

        </div>
</body>
```

Here is mittens.js file..

```
var app = angular.module('mittens',[]);

    app.controller('mittensController',function($scope){

        $scope.meows = [{
            'This is first sentence',
            'This is second sentence',
            'This is third sentence',
            'This is fourth sentence'
        }];

    });
```

Comment: try this  `<h3 ng-repeat="meow in meows[0]">{{meow}}</h3>`

Comment: As SSH said. You have packed your data into the first column of an array.

Comment: Actually it's not working though...
I had tried it only with square bracket...
But it's not though working....

Comment: Remove the {} also.

Comment: No it's not working @McBoman

Comment: If you're not getting any error in console, and you're getting the raw uncompiled html, check that you have included your scripts properly.

Comment: @Ladmerc Thank you lad,....
I had used href instead of src in linking those js files.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the reference link for mittens.js is wrongly loaded. You should use `src` instead of `href`

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="mittens">
    <head>
        <title>Mittens</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" href="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="mittens.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body ng-controller="mittensController">
        <div class="container">

            <h3 ng-repeat="meow in meows">{{meow}}</h3>
        </div>
</body>
```

Script:

```
    var app = angular.module('mittens',[]);
            app.controller('mittensController',function($scope){

                $scope.meows = [
                    'This is first sentence',
                    'This is second sentence',
                    'This is third sentence',
                    'This is fourth sentence'
                ]; //removed {} braces
            });
```

UPDATE: here is the Plunker [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/fKhYtUrKcGIYOnmbgqpr?p=preview) if you want to reference.

Comment: I changed the way you mentioned, But seems like nothing working.. no console side error...

Comment: @WebFlash try now. u mentioned href. where as it should be `<script src="mittens.js"></script>` i.e 'src' instead of 'href'

Comment: @WebFlash if it work please accept the answer for other to reference from

Comment: how to do that?
I wanted to upvote all the answers but it's showing me an error something with 15 reputation....

Comment: @WebFlash you dont need to upvote you just need to accept the answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: ohk.. i accepted your answer... thanks for helping.. :)

Answer (score 1):

`ng-repeat` directive works on either an Array or an object but you are attempting to work on an Array with only one object which is also defined incorrectly.

A Javascript Object is defined like: `{foo: 'Some bar', bar: 'Some foo'}`

So try changing your code like this below working code:

```js
var app = angular.module('mittens', []);

app.controller('mittensController', function($scope) {

  $scope.meows = [    // <<< remove bracket from here
    'This is first sentence',
    'This is second sentence',
    'This is third sentence',
    'This is fourth sentence'
  ];   // <<< also remove from here

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mittens" ng-controller="mittensController">
  <div class="container">

    <h3 ng-repeat="meow in meows">{{meow}}</h3>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually It's not working...
I have done everything and i have already done this before...
But in this case there is not any error but it's not working...
By the way i can't find those two js files in sources tab... Can that be a problem?

Comment: I found the solution... I used href instead of src in linking js files... 
By the way.. thanks though.. :)  @shashank